# how to rotate file while doing a streaming transfer to google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

We are working on a POC where we want to stream our web logs to google cloud storage. We learnt that objects on google cloud storage are immutable and cannot be appended from java api. However, we can do streaming transfers using gsutil according to this link https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques?hl=en#streaming
Now we would like to write hourly files. Is there a way to change the file name every hour like logrotate?

Answer (score 0):

gsutil doesn't offer any logrotate-style features for object naming.

With a gsutil streaming transfer, the resulting cloud object is named according to the destination object in your `gsutil cp` command.  To achieve rotation, your job that produces the stream could close the stream on an hourly basis, select a new filename, and issue a new streaming gsutil cp command.

Comment: Thanks for the update. We just found gcsfuse utility can solve our problem. We are trying that for now. Will update soon.